# setFrame on subviews of tableViewHeader not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, frame

I have a tableViewHeader UIView that contains a few dynamic elements (UILabels with varying sizes to be exact). I set the UIView up in IB, have everything connected up, and am trying to change frame origins based on the size of my labels after sizeToFit.

If I log the new frames after my setFrame call, it actually does show the updated origins, but they don't display on the simulator. The labels change height, but the origins do not change.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
CGRect frame;
CGFloat baseOffset = titleLbl.frame.origin.y;
offset = titleLbl.frame.size.height;
self.titleLbl.text = destObject.title;
self.titleLbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Heavy" size:22];
[self.titleLbl sizeToFit];
frame = titleLbl.frame;
frame.origin.y = baseOffset;
//Get any change in size from the label
offset = titleLbl.frame.size.height - offset;

frame = imageView.frame;
frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + offset;
self.imageView.frame = frame;

frame = photosBtn.frame;
frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + offset;
[self.photosBtn setFrame:frame];

frame = detailLbl.frame;
frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + offset;
self.detailLbl.frame = frame;
baseOffset = self.detailLbl.frame.origin.y;
CGFloat detailOffset = self.detailLbl.frame.size.height;
self.detailLbl.text = destObject.description;
[self.detailLbl sizeToFit];
frame = detailLbl.frame;
frame.origin.y = baseOffset;
self.detailLbl.frame = frame;
detailOffset = self.detailLbl.frame.size.height - detailOffset;
offset = offset + detailOffset;

frame = blueLine.frame;
frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + offset;
self.blueLine.frame = frame;

self.whereToDiveLbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Heavy" size:22];
frame = whereToDiveLbl.frame;
frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + offset;
self.whereToDiveLbl.frame = frame;

frame = grayLine.frame;
frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + offset;
self.grayLine.frame = frame;

frame = CGRectMake(headerView.frame.origin.x, headerView.frame.origin.y, headerView.frame.size.width, grayLine.frame.size.height + grayLine.frame.origin.y + 5);
self.headerView.frame = frame;
}
```

I've tried looking around for similar issues, but couldn't find any. Can anyone shed some light on this?

I should point out that the UIView itself (that is, headerView in this case) DOES reflect changes to its frame on the simulator, but its subviews do not. I have autoresize subviews enabled if it makes any difference, but I get the same result enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out that my UIView in IB had 'Use Autolayout' checked under Identity and Type...deselecting this solved my problem.

Comment: Wow, this was driving me crazy, I had a button that had a default position, but i was setting it to the 'correct' position at runtime, but it wasn't applying the first time, only the second. Like: first time: infoButton: {{541, 504}, {32, 32}} -> {{541, 420.786}, {32, 32}}, second time: infoButton: {{541, 504}, {32, 32}} -> {{541, 420.786}, {32, 32}}, after the second time it stayed at the correct coordinates, but i couldn't figure out why it was resetting. I turned off autolayout for the xib and then it worked! dunno what was happening...